# Django crispy-forms wrap all not working

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-crispy-forms

Why doesn't this work?
(Django 1.7 and django-crispy-forms 1.4.0)

The css class is not being applied.

```
class ResourceForm(ModelForm):

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(ResourceForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.helper = FormHelper(self)
    self.helper.layout = Layout()
    self.helper.add_input(Submit('submit', 'Submit'))
    self.helper.all().wrap(Field, css_class="col-xs-3 col-sm-4")


class Meta:
    model = Resource
    fields = ['title',
              '....
```

And then the form html:

```
 {% load crispy_forms_tags %}

{% block content %}
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 main_column">
    {% crispy form form.helper %}
</div>

{% endblock %}
```

The form html generated looks like this:

```
<form  method="post"  enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type='hidden' name='csrfmiddlewaretoken' value='blaahblahblah...' /> 
    <div id="div_id_title" class="form-group">
        <label for="id_title" class="control-label  requiredField">
            Title<span class="asteriskField">*</span>
        </label>
        <div class="controls ">
            <input class="textinput textInput form-control" id="id_title" maxlength="255" name="title" type="text" value="Foo" /> 
        </div>
    </div>
....
</form>
```

That is, the normal html for a ModelForm.
Note that I'm using `forms.ModelForm`, not `forms.Form`.

Comment: What HTML code does it currently generate? Thanks.

Comment: I'll add generated html to the question above.

Comment: What if you would replace `FormHelper(self)` with `FormHelper()`?

Comment: Removing the 'self" has no effect on this problem. But I'm sure it would cause others. Is there some reason you suggested it?

Comment: No reason at all, just seen both usages. Ok, can you check if it is about using `all()` and try with a single field?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you call `FormHelper` with a form passed in

```
self.helper = FormHelper(self)
```

it automaticaly creates a layout with all fields included like this ([see the code](https://github.com/maraujop/django-crispy-forms/blob/1.4.0/crispy_forms/helper.py#L212)):

```
def __init__(self, form=None):
    self.attrs = {}
    self.inputs = []

    if form is not None:
        self.form = form
        self.layout = self.build_default_layout(form)
```

But then when you call

```
self.helper.layout = Layout()
```

you destroy it. So you have no fields to wrap.

**The solution:** remove the line `self.helper.layout = Layout()`

Comment: This is the answer, but the docs seem to contradict it entirely. See: http://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.org/en/d-0/dynamic_layouts.html?highlight=wrap#all